# UIPageViewController inside UIScrollView first swipe fails

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

My View looks like this:

```
UIViewController {
    UIScrollView {
        UIPageViewController {
            UIViewController {
                UIScrollView {

                }
                .direction(.horizontal)
            }
            UIViewController {
                UIScrollView {

                }
                .direction(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And there is the problem, which seems pretty unexpected. When you try to swipe first time the `UIPageViewController` starts scrolling, **but** when you do the same the second time the inner horizontal `UIScrollView` starts first.

I've tried a lot of variants with gestures, cancel touches, delegates, nothing worked.

**Playground project**:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGNDp3cDuGRo8ywpYRH8J93dCDqt96Ai/view?usp=sharing

[**Video**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P4yh.gif)